# Cannot find config module when running mocha but works when running nodemon

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

When I run my server:

from my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "grunt & nodemon ./dist/server.js",
    "test": "mocha"
},
```

from my server.coffee file:

```
config = require './config'
```

Everything works fine, but when I run my test I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './config'
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

The config is not loaded in test/users.coffee, it is loaded from the server.coffee file which is loaded into tests/users.coffee

`server = require '../src/server/server'`

Answer (score 0):

The `require` path will be different from your test directory.

```
 config = require './src/server/config'
```

Comment: I edited my question to show where the config file is actually loaded